# DrawString without trimming

Tags: c#, xna, drawstring

How can I use the `DrawString` function and send it a `rectangle` (to set the alignment)? If the text is longer from the rectangle's width then the line will continue until the end of the line? 
(not multi line case!!)

Comment: What do you want to happen if the text is longer than the width of the rectangle? Truncate the text? Wrap it to another line?

Comment: Are you trying to make sure you're filling an entire area with the text? Do you want to overwrite what's beneath? Then I suggest you do a `FillRectangle` first, to clear the text background.

Comment: You may need to `MeasureString` first and adjust the rectangle accordingly so that the text fits.

Comment: @user2949943 You mean, if the test is longer than a certain width, it will simply stop? Instead of extending?

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension method to remove any text outside of the horizontal destination region. (I assume this is what you meant) It adds an option ellipsis to the text (`...`) to let users know the text continues.

```
public static void DrawStringTrim(this SpriteBatch spriteBatch, SpriteFont font, Rectangle rect, string text, Color color)
{
    // Characters to append to end of text, can be removed.
    string ellipsis = "...";

    // Get the width of the text string.
    int size = (int)Math.Ceiling(font.MeasureString(text).X);

    // Is text longer than the destination region? If not, simply draw it
    if (size > rect.Width)
    {
        // Account for the length of the "..." (ellipsis) string.
        int es = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ellipsis) ? 0 : (int)Math.Ceiling(font.MeasureString(ellipsis).X);
        for (int i = text.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int c = 1;

            // Remove two letters if the preceding character is a space.
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i - 1]))
            {
                c = 2;
                i--;
            }

            // Chop off the tail of the string and re-measure the width.
            text = text.Remove(i, c);
            size = (int)Math.Ceiling(font.MeasureString(text).X);

            // Text is short enough?
            if (size + es <= rect.Width)
                break;
        }

        // Append the ellipsis to the truncated string.
        text += ellipsis;
    }

    // Draw the text
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text, new Vector2(rect.X, rect.Y), color);
}
```

You can then draw the string you want with `spriteBatch.DrawStringTrim(font, new Rectangle(Width, Height), "Some really really long text!", Color.White);`